# Please update to Node >=14 and npm >=6. But I have higher versions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I just created a react app using create-react-app and I get the following message:

```
Note: the project was bootstrapped with an old unsupported version of tools.
Please update to Node >=14 and npm >=6 to get supported tools in new projects.
```

But I have node version 16.16.0 and npm version 8.10.0. So what does it mean? Am I OK?

PS: I don't know if it's relevant, but I am on Ubuntu 20.04LTS.

Comment: Greetings! When you do **node -v** and **npm -v** in the console you get 16 & 8? If so, you should be fine :) Although I think it's weird that it shows you that note. Happy to follow if someone else knows the answer to this.

Comment: node -v and npm -v do indeed show just that.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, no idea why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete both `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`

```
run npm i web-vitals --save-dev
run npm install
```

and then you can use `npm run build` and `npm start` again.

If these don't work, you can try

```
yarn cache clean
yarn install
```

and then `npx create-react-app your-app`. Hope it helps!